# php - multidimensional array foreach only returns one result

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am a begginer with php, i have a variable, what sotres information about an uploaded image

I get a multidimensional array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [errors] => Array
                (
                )

            [path] => addons/uploads/albums/1/1/rDtKgyVAvTjSkLA.jpg
            [filename] => rDtKgyVAvTjSkLA.jpg
            [original_name] => rachaelCache_5750270_thm.jpg
            [resizes] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 1
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [errors] => Array
                (
                )

            [path] => addons/uploads/albums/1/1/qTLglBgAPxvDFtr.png
            [filename] => qTLglBgAPxvDFtr.png
            [original_name] => Screen Shot 2013-03-02 at 11.28.48 AM.png
            [resizes] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

but when i foreach it i only get one result back

```
foreach ($upload as $row) {
   echo $row['filename'];
}
```

could please someone tell me why is this happening?

Comment: I'm assuming that the array you're showing in the question is $upload. What exactly is the output of the foreach loop?

Comment: Based on the assumptions being made about your code, it should work.  I created the Array in your code in a PHP fiddle with the foreach loop you show.  It works as expected. http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ekn-fxd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recreated your code as live-demo, works just fine: ---> http://3v4l.org/986e7

```
$upload = array(array(
        'errors' => array(), 
        'filename' => '/some/path/to/a/file.jpg'), 
    array(
        'errors' => array(), 
        'filename' => '/yet/another/path.jpg'));

var_dump($upload);

foreach ($upload as $x) 
    echo $x['filename'],"<br>";

echo $upload[0]['filename'];
```

To find out what is wrong, I'd put a `var_dump($upload);` right before your `foreach`-loop to see if $upload holds what you think it holds.